Call to undefined method Intervention\Image\EncodedImage::getRealPath()
<?php

use Intervention\Image\Image;

class WatermarkStrategy
{
    
    /**
     *
     * @param  mixed $fileImage uploaded file
     * @return Image
     */
    public function snap($fileImage): Image
    {
        $imageManager = app('ImageManager');

        $uploadedFile = $imageManager->read($fileImage);

        // apply water mark 
        $modifiedImage = $this->apply(
            $uploadedFile,
            ['position' => 'top-left', 'opacity' => 100]
        );

        return $modifiedImage;
    }



    public function apply(Image $uploadedFile, mixed $value): Image
    {

        try {
            $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
            $response = $client->get('s3/watermark.jpg');

            $imageContent = $response->getBody()->getContents();

            // error was thrown in here cuz intervention image can't read the image from s3,but i need to read that image from s3 and place as watermark
            $waterMark = app("ImageManager")->read($imageContent);

            return $uploadedFile->place(
            $waterMark, 
            $value['position'], 
            opacity: $value['opacity']);

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Watermark image not found');
        }
    }
}

Problem
The function throws an error because Intervention Image v3 doesn’t allow creating images from a URI directly. My goal is to retrieve the watermark image from a cloud provider, process it, and place it on the uploaded image.
Question
How can I fetch an image from a cloud URI, process it, and use it as a watermark in Intervention Image v3? Is there an alternative approach or workaround for this limitation?
Tech :framework : Laravel 10, package : image intervention v3 , storage : s3
